# SubClass Mapping in NHibernate by using same table

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have one table. That is s.
There are two classes 1. `S` and 2. `P`

Plate is inherited from S. The classes are:

```
public class S
{
    public virtual decimal Id { get; set; }        
    public virtual IList<P> ChildPs { get; set; }
}

public class P : S
{
    public virtual GType GType { get; set; }
}

internal class SMap : ClassMap<S>
{
    public SMap()
    {
        Table("s");
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("A_S_ID");
        /* Set Parent_S_Id */
        HasMany<P>(x => x.ChildPs)
            .KeyColumn("PARENT_A_S_ID")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

internal class PMap : SubclassMap<P>
{
    public PMap()
    {
        References(x => x.GType)
             .Column("G_TYPE_ID")
             .ForeignKey("G_TYPE_LU_ID");
    }
}
```

I created a `S` instance and add some `P` to `ChildP`. When I save the `S` instance then it gives the error `P is not exist`. Anyone have any idea about this?

Please share your view.

Comment: How do you know if a row in the `structure` table is a `Structure` or `Plate` type? What is the discriminator between them?

Comment: PARENT_ASSET_STRUCTURE_ID is a column. It is used to save Structure_id (Parent ID) for plates. For structure is NULL.

Comment: @jugal : You want a solution for subclass without using discriminator.....!!

Answer (score 0):

Your inheritance mapping settings are "table-per-subclass". That is mean that you will have different tables for different classes.
I am not sure, but it seems to me that you can't save, because you have only 1 table.
You can find additional information [here](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping), at section Subclasses.

Comment: You can also find good post on that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat)